# Bootstrap Carousel slider does not wait until next image is loaded successfully

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

Is there any way to wait Carousel slider in cycle effect until the next image being downloaded.
Right now i use below code for carousel.

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval:4000
});
```

Above code working on time interval but does not wait until the next image is loaded completely.

Comment: Is the image you use in the carousel a quality-optimized or size-reduced one for web use?

Comment: i used 6 imgs that all images size between 500kb to 700kb. i use images in web apps full screen slideshow.

Comment: 500 and 700 kb are too much.. Thats not a good practice. Try saving your pictures for web, using softwares like gimp with 60-80 qulaity. Google "Resize and save images for web".

Comment: i like your suggestion but i need to load high quality img.

Answer (score 1):

There is not way the carousel wait until image is loaded for the next slide. but you can do one thing is that you can generate img tag of carousel at runtime as follow and you can use its onload event:

```
var theImage = new Image();
theImage.src = encodeURI(ImagePath);
theImage.onload = function () {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('next')      \\this statement will slide to next after image is loaded
}
$('body').append(theImage);
```

Comment: Thanks Innodel, i implement your code in loop and when i go to last image execute $('#myCarousel').carousel("cycle");